# Find polynomial over a ring with nine roots

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I've been asked to find a polynomial $f \in {\mathbf Z}_{21}[x]$ such that $\deg f = 3$ and nine distinct roots of $f$ exist.

Does this question make any sense to you? I mean, $\mathbf{Z}_{21}$ is not an integral domain, so things like divisibility are not defined.

The hint in the exercise says, "try using the Chinese remainder theorem". Is this a typo or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need divisibility. In order to speak about polynomials and their roots, you only need a ring.

A first try can be something like
$$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$

This polynomial clearly has (at least) three roots: namely $a$, $b$ and $c$. If $21$ were a prime number, then our ring would be an integral domain (a field, in fact) and there would be no more roots. But $3\cdot 7=21$, so if $v-a$ is a multiple fo $3$ and $v-b$ is a multiple of $7$, then $f(v)=0$, that is, $v$ would be a root.

Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: I see! Thanks, I will try that now.

Comment: Thank you, @ajotatxe, how could I have not seen this?